# HTMLUNIT Facebook javascript warning

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, htmlunit

I am trying to create simple application that would be able to search people on facebook using given e-mail. I am already able to log into an account using the HTMLunit tool and even create a page, which should throw result of my search. But when I try to print the result as XML the file is missing some blocks of javascript results (I can tell that they are missing by comparing file created by my application and source code, that can be viewed by using IE)

Is there any way around this? I just need to get the same result IE's showsource function does.

Thanks a lot.

During execution of file, I am getting these WARNINGS:

```
1.4.2010 23:25:14 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/z49PH/hash/9p47jvzp.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
21.4.2010 23:25:14 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/z5N5C/hash/dhdy6xq3.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
21.4.2010 23:25:14 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/z4TLI/hash/9ucb5trt.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z49PH/hash/9p47jvzp.js', but got 'application/x-javascript'.
```

And then a lot of CSS errors

```
    21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [44:92] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [44:92] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [51:75] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [51:75] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [161:62] Error in style rule. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", <COMMA>, ";", "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, <URI>, "!", "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [161:62] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [134:25] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [134:25] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [140:175] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [140:175] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [157:38] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [158:128] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [158:128] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [197:16] Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [197:16] Ignoring the whole rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [218:58] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [218:58] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [349:141] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [349:141] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [356:101] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [356:106] Error in style rule. Invalid token "opacity". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [356:106] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [360:87] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [360:93] Error in style rule. Invalid token "opacity". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [360:93] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [365:39] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [365:43] Error in style rule. Invalid token "left". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [365:43] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [423:51] Error in style rule. Invalid token "~". Was expecting one of: <S>, <LBRACE>, <COMMA>, <PLUS>, <GREATER>, <IDENT>, "*", <HASH>, ".", "[", ":".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [423:51] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [466:135] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [466:135] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [501:30] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [501:30] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [584:59] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [584:64] Error in style rule. Invalid token "opacity". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [584:64] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [585:36] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [585:36] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [592:120] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [592:125] Error in style rule. Invalid token "opacity". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [592:125] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [598:44] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [598:48] Error in style rule. Invalid token "left". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [598:48] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [601:52] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [601:52] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [637:89] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [637:89] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [648:56] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [648:56] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [656:289] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [656:289] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [660:48] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [660:55] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-ms-filter". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [660:55] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [664:29] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [664:29] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [669:22] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [669:22] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [673:231] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [673:231] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [674:17] Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [674:17] Ignoring the whole rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [690:81] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [690:87] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-ms-filter". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [690:87] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [693:84] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [693:91] Error in style rule. Invalid token "-ms-filter". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [693:91] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [695:32] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [695:32] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [702:32] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [702:32] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [703:17] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [703:17] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [705:166] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [705:166] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [706:21] Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [706:21] Ignoring the whole rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [101:1] Error in declaration. Invalid token "}". Was expecting one of: <S>, ":".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [101:2] Error in style rule. Invalid token "\n". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [101:2] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [185:39] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [185:39] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [186:38] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [186:38] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [235:84] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [235:84] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [290:26] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [290:26] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [291:70] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [291:70] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [298:52] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [298:52] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [299:48] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [299:48] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [305:50] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [305:50] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [306:69] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [306:69] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [307:89] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [307:89] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [309:83] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [309:83] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [317:84] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [317:84] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [473:215] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [473:215] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [475:137] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [475:137] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [480:78] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [480:78] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:23 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [484:78] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [484:78] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [486:91] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [486:91] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [498:16] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [498:16] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [506:33] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [506:33] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [508:14] Error in pseudo class or element. Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [508:14] Ignoring the whole rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [567:82] Error in expression. Invalid token "=". Was expecting one of: <S>, <COMMA>, "/", <PLUS>, "-", <HASH>, <STRING>, ")", <URI>, "inherit", <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <DIMENSION>, <PERCENTAGE>, <NUMBER>, <FUNCTION>, <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [567:86] Error in style rule. Invalid token "opacity". Was expecting one of: "}", ";".
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning: null [567:86] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: null [572:159] Error in style rule. Invalid token "*". Was expecting one of: <S>, "}", ";", <IDENT>.
21.4.2010 23:25:24 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
WARNING: CSS warning:
```

Comment: Web scraping is against Facebook's TOS agreement. I'd suggest looking into Facebook's developer resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting another `BrowserVersion`